# How to declare a let constant of datatype NSFetchRequest without knowing the entity that should be fetched yet

Tags: swift, core-data

I am developing an app using Core Data.
Let's say I have 5 entities in my data model: A, B, C, D, E.

In my home screen there are five buttons, if you push one of the buttons you will go to a tableviewcontroller where the information from one of the entities is fetched, depending on the button you pushed.

In my tableviewcontroller I have to define:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<entityname> = entityname.fetchRequest()
```

However, "entityname" depends on which button you pushed and you will never know until it is pushed and passed to the viewController.

How can I define this constant without knowing the entity that will be called?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. You can use the method:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: typeOfDocument!)
```

Where typeOfDocument is a var String? that is modified in the prepareForSegue of the HomeViewController.